# What if _xbegin(); leads to a segmentation fault?

Tags: concurrency, intel, transactional-memory

I'm trying to compile the following [TSX sample code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-transactional-memory-intrinsics.html) on an [Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz that supports TSX](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i7/i7-7700k) using `gcc tsc.x -mrtm`:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int max_tries=100;
unsigned status = _XABORT_EXPLICIT;


int main(){

    for (int n_tries = 0; n_tries < max_tries; n_tries++) 
    {
        status = _xbegin();
        if (status == _XBEGIN_STARTED || !(status & _XABORT_RETRY))
        {
                break;
        }

        if(status == _XBEGIN_STARTED) 
        {
                printf("TSX started\n");
                _xend ();
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("TSX failed\n");
        }

    }


return 0;
}
```

But the output would either result into "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" or simply no output and in rare cases TSX failed. But never TSX started.

Comment: Does your OS enable (or not disable) TSX?  Most do disable it because of possible security problems with side-channels and stuff like that, especially TAA (TSX Asynchronous Abort, CVE-2019-11135): https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html  Your program tries to use TSX features without checking CPUID to see if they're available.

Comment: [Assembler xbegin raise Illegal instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59209610) says CPUID may actually still show it enabled even though it's disabled.

Comment: Assuming you're using Linux, does `dmesg | grep -i tsx` say something like `TAA: Mitigation: TSX disabled`?  If so, yeah SIGILL is probably to be expected.  (I've tried booting with `tsx_async_abort=off tsx=on` but 6.0.7-arch1-1 Linux says it doesn't recognize the `tsx=on` part, and disables TSX anyway.  :/  IDK if an Arch Linux patch took out support for that option which kernel.org documents, but Arch generally doesn't do a lot of patching vs. upstream)

Comment: No, TSX is definitely on.

Comment: @PeterCordes Is TSX suppose to support printf()?

Comment: Generally no, and definitely not if it flushes the IO buffer requiring a system call!  Then you'll always get a transaction abort.